# Go back at the beginning of a foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

Is it possible ? Or should I end the loop and beginning another ?

```
foreach($array as $i)
{
    if (something)
        // Go back
}
```

Comment: no you can't reset it, but `while` can though

Comment: Make a function, and use break + call same function again if you need to.

Comment: What do you really need? Breaking `foreach` loop is probably bad way how to do it.

Comment: @panther I have a String array. The initial string is date, like : "28, 29 Fevrier" (in French). And when I meet a month, I would like to save it in a variable, and go back at the beginning of my array -> 28

Comment: @HugoTor: string array? Hm, you explode string to array? If you have string, use regex to get Month and date(s).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is. But not with foreach & without leaving the loop.
Here's another alternative, for good measure.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
  if (condition) {
    $i = 0;
  }
  do_stuff_with($array[$i]);
}
```

Comment: I feel stupid now.. I'm working with `foreach` loop only, and I don't thought to the simle `for` loop, which will work easily (I hope !)

Answer (score 2):

It is not suggested but you can use goto:

```
cIterator: { 
foreach($array as $i)
{
    if (something)
        goto cIterator; 
}
}
```

Comment: Remind me Visual Basic ! Not sure it is the cleaner solution to my ask :/ But if I don't resolve my problem with @b0s3 function, I'll try this :)

Comment: @HugoTor your question has a goto nature by itself... BTW, goto reminds me the qbasic (feeling olddddd ;) )

Comment: I wasn't born when qBasic appeared haha! Will try both, and keep the more maintainable for the future

Answer (score 1):

Create a function and pass the array. If something happens in the loop call the function again with the main array. Try this -

```
function check_loop($array) {
   foreach($array as $val) {
      if (something)
         check_loop($array);
   }
}
check_loop($array);
```

Comment: Will try this solution, seems more understandable (I'm not alone to work on this project), and efficient. Will give you a feedback

Answer (score 1):

You can use current(), next() and prev() to loop through array and move the internal array pointer back and forth:

```
$items = array("apple", "box", "cat");
while($item=current($items)) {
    print_r($item);
    if (needToGoBack($item))
        // Go to previous array item
        $item = reset($items);
    } else {
        // Continue to next
        $item = next($items);
    }
}
```

Comment: But with next&prev, I can only go back to the precedent item ? Or maybe using them in another loop to do prev/prev/prev etc., but not sure it's the faster solution :/

Comment: @HugoTor: Next will iterate through the array and if the condition to move back is satisfied, the prev() will move to previous item. I thought you wanted to go back to previous array item for some condition?

Comment: Not the previous, but the beginning

Comment: @HugoTor. Then you can simply use `reset($items)` instead of `prev($items)`. I have edited the answer.

Comment: Ok, didn't know this function ! :) And I have to iterate into a while loop ?

Comment: Yup this is a `while()` loop and it will terminate when there is no more item in the current array index.

Answer (score 0):

Use *continue*

From the PHP docs:  *continue* is used within looping structures to skip the rest of the current loop iteration and continue execution at the condition evaluation and then the beginning of the next iteration.

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php